# Yii - How to validate a textfield for text only

Tags: yii, textfield

I need to create a validation to textfield only allow me to enter text no number and no symbols. text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the following rule, where attribute is the name of the textfield

```
array('attribute', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[a-zA-Z]+$/'),
```

Check out this link to see all build in validation options: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/

Comment: I worked perfect. It only agrege the symbol "+" 

array ('attribute', 'match', 'pattern' => '/ ^ [a-zA-Z] + $ /'),

Comment: If you want to enter such spaces to place both names, so you can use it: array('nombres, apellidos', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[a-zA-Z[:space:]]+$/'),